# Es posible remover la suscripcion a un evento sin un método asociado C#

Tags: c#, eventos

Estoy trabajando en WPF, y por un tema de requerimientos debo usar el evento `Closing` para deshabilitar la salida del programa.

Se que teniendo un método asociado es posible agregar y remover eventos haciendo uso de `+=` y `-=`

```
this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
this.Closing -= MainWindow_Closing;
private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
      e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Pero en caso de definir el evento sin un método asociado, de la siguiente manera

```
this.Closing += (sender, e) => { e.Cancel = false; };
```

¿es posible remover este evento?

Comment: probaste con This.Closing += null?

Comment: @gbianchi probé, pero sigue suscrito

Comment: Creo que el problema es que el segundo evento es anonimo. No sabria como decirle que se desuscriba de un evento anonimo. Si vas a necesitar desuscribirte, no uses un evento anonimo...

Comment: y aca esta tu respuesta.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/183367/73749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado de este modo?

```
System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler closingEventHandler = (s, e) => {
    // tu código
    e.Cancel = true;
};

// creo que esto también funciona
var closingEventHandler = new CancelEventHandler((s, e) => {
    // tu código
    e.Cancel = true;
});

this.Closing += closingEventHandler ;

// mas adelante...

this.Closing -= closingEventHandler;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Luis, funcionó utilizando `CancelEventHandler` en lugar de `Action<object,CancelEventArgs>`, de la siguiente manera: `System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler closingEventHandler = (s, e) => {
                // tu código
                e.Cancel = true;
            };`, si podes, modifica la respuesta así la doy como correcta

Comment: Listo, puse otra forma de incializar, al menos me ha funcionado en Winforms, y en lo personal me gusta mas ;)